# Detect Contours and Text Blocks

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to work on text recognition from the image. The main aim is to extract key factors from the image, say for a product label, I want to identify its ingredients and nutrition. The problem is images are not standard in size. I'm attaching some samples - [sample 1](https://ibb.co/bW0Nxe) and [sample 2](https://ibb.co/cwT9ce). I have tried multiple approaches mainly with canny edge detection, robert cross, laplacian and gaussian encoding, but the results are not the same on every image. I might be missing something here. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def channel(image):
    accumEdged = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
    for chan in cv2.split(image):
        mean = np.mean(chan)
        min_value = 0.66*mean
        max_value = 1.33*mean
        chan = cv2.GaussianBlur(chan, (7,7), 0)
        edged = cv2.Canny(chan, min_value, max_value)
        accumEdged = cv2.bitwise_xor(accumEdged, edged)

    return accumEdged, min_value, max_value

temp = []

for item in os.listdir(image_dir):
    img = "/home/abc/Test images/" + item
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    base_image = cv2.imread(img)
    length, width = base_image.shape[:2]
    edge, min_value, max_value = channel(image)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(edge.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    threshold_area = 10000

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 5)
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 35))
threshed = cv2.morphologyEx(edge.copy(), cv2.MORPH_OPEN, rect_kernel)
(_, cnts_alt, _) = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

idx = 0
cnts.extend(cnts_alt)
threshold_area = 10000
for c in cnts:
    area1 = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area1 > 10000:
        hull = cv2.convexHull(c)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(hull)
        area = w*h
        temp.append([area1, area])
        if area > 10000:
            idx += 1
            new_img_1=base_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            out_path = '/home/abc/Test images/'+item.split('.')[0]+'/'+str(idx)+'.png'
            cv2.imwrite(out_path, new_img_1)
            cv2.rectangle(base_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 5)
path = '/home/abc/Test images/'+item.split('.')[0]+'.png'   
cv2.imwrite(path, base_image)
```

Comment: describe one of your attempts, currently written answer is too broad

Comment: I thought the code will stretch the question. I have 3-4 approaches but none is working perfectly on all cases.